# Query SetupAuditTrail doesn't directly relate a metadata component

Tags: api, metadata, setup-audit-log

Even though the capacity to query `SetupAuditTrail` object [was introduced in Winter '16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_api_objects_new.htm#sat), it seems targeted mostly for reporting or human-readable purposes since the affected metadata (for changes that do affect metadata) and the action applied to it (create, modify, delete) is located in the `Display` field, which is also dependant on the language of the user issuing the query.

Is there a way to obtain the metadata component being altered without having to parse the `Display` message?

Comment: No OOB way AFAIK. You could check app exchange or other discussion forums to check if there is any app or tool available to facilitate this. For example, this [tool](https://github.com/ysfdc/AuditLogScanner) seems to allow specify filters and generate emails when the filter conditions are met.